# Which Transfer Syntax to select for the C-FIND Service Class?

Tags: dicom

I want to search for remote patients, studies...images using the DICOM C-FIND Service Class.
DICOM Part 5 offers a phletory of possible encodings (Transfer Syntaxes) - which one should I choose?

Answer (score 1):

For C-FIND, the minimum DICOM requirement is supporting Implicit Little Endian (Transfer Syntax UID: 1.2.840.10008.1.2).

That means, you can rely on any DICOM conformant server to support it and you cannot expect that all DICOM conformant servers support something else (although most of them do).

[Reference in the DICOM standard](https://dicom.nema.org/dicom/2013/output/chtml/part05/chapter_10.html)